# C#: How can I make automapper map a property of type object?

Tags: c#, automapper

This is the source object:

```
public class Source {
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Here object is actually a `SourcePropertyType`.

I want to convert Source to this:

```
public class Destination {
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}
```

where object is `DestinationPropertyType` (which is identical to `SourcePropertyType`)

```
var destination = map.Map<Source, Destination>(source);
var myObj = destination.Obj as DestinationPropertyType;
```

In the above code `myObj == null` even if Obj on the source is set.

I hope this makes sense. How can I change the AutoMapper configuration so that it understands that the destination is a `DestinationPropertyType` and maps it as it would normally?

Comment: Why are you using `object` as the type instead of the _actual_ type if it's always that type?

Comment: It is an autogenerated wsdl proxy class. For some reason it is an object...

Answer (score 2):

By "identical to `SourcePropertyType`" I am assuming you mean that they have the same properties and types.  In that case, you just need to have AutoMapper make a map between the two and configure the map for the containing type to use it:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourcePropertyType, DestinationPropertyType>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ForMember(d => d.obj,
                 o => o.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<DestinationPropertyType>(s.obj As SourcePropertyType) as Object);
```

Note that if the property types were the *actual* types instead of `object` you wouldn't need the extra configuration.

Comment: My version of automapper no longer supports the static way of doing the mapping, do you have a more updated version? I am not sure how to use a mapping while doing the configuration...

Comment: No - I haven't used the newer versions of automapper.  But the idea should be the same: create a map, cast the source object, map it, cast it back to object.

Answer (score 0):

Unbox the objects to specific types before you run it through Automapper. Automapper will not be able to map an object to an object.